# Связи между формами

Tags: windows, c++

У меня имеется form1, на ней размещены кнопки. Что мне нужно прописать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку у меня выскакивало form2 (в новом окне), а на form2 у меня есть кнопка назад, что нужно прописать в ней, чтобы при её нажатии вернуться на form1?

Comment: Так в билдере,майкрософт не знаю.
Чтобы открыть новую форму(обработка нажатия):  
<pre><code>Form2->Show();</code></pre>
Ее надо подключить в первой форме   
<pre><code>#include "Unit2.h"</code></pre>
Чтобы закрыть(обработка нажатия на второй форме):  
<pre><code>Form2->Close();</code></pre>(т.к. по умолчанию первая форма основная, то на нее и вернетесь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я про C++ точно не знаю, но в C# я бы сделал так,

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

А при нажатии на кнопку на второй форме было бы так

```
this.Hide();
```

Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Все правильно понял.
Но на С# я тоже знаю, хотелось бы узнать как делать на С или С++...